# How should I design a left-right UI where the left is smaller?

Tags: website-design, page-layout

This is the current design:

[image]

Where should I position the left-top element so this UI is more balanced?

Comment: I would move the image in and down a bit so that the margin/padding (gap to the outer edge) is the same as the margin you have around your QR code. Having consistent spacing is easier on the eyes IMO.

Comment: The more information you add to your question, the more detailed the answers will be. I would perhaps change 'enjoyable' (which sounds subjective) to something like 'balanced'. In any case, welcome to GD.SE!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have two suggestions, depending on the aim of this product:

1) Can the image thumbnail be bigger? I would make the thumbnail roughly the same height as the QR Code and incorporate @John feedback.

[image]

2) Is that QR code simply for that one thumbnail? or are there going to be more thumbnails per QR code? If the latter, I would create 5 more gray boxes the same size as the original thumbnail and lay them out on a nice grid, so you have a 2 rows of 3 boxes.

[image]